# Plotting Closing price of SBIN NSE but it is plotting 3:30pm-9:15am also

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, finance, stock, mplfinance

the dataframe only have time from 9:15 am to 3:30pm every working day. but when it is getting plotted as chart, matplotlib is plotting times between 3:30 to 9:15 next day now tell the solution

[image: here is the plotted result]

can't figure out how to get continuous figure & [here is the csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oDgL8TTC2zE5BPEFHQ92fBAFkxGeH5mA/view?usp=share_link)

i tried using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#data = the read file in the link
data = pd.read_csv('sbin.csv')

plt.plot(data['MA_50'], label='MA 50', color='red')
plt.plot(data['MA_10'], label='MA 10', color='blue')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim(data.index[0], data.index[-1])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Price')plt.show()
```

I expect again 9:15 after 3:30

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [**`mplfinance`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials) ?

Using the data you posted:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sbin.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

mpf.plot(df, type='candle', ema=(10,50), style='yahoo')
```

The result:

[image]